# A kernel module to transparently detour packets coming from a NIC and TCP application. Is it possible to make it done?

Tags: c, networking, tcp, kernel

Is it possible for a Linux kernel module to transparently detour the packet coming from upper layer (i.e. L2,L3) and NIC? For example, **1)** a packet arrives from a NIC, the module gets the packet (do some processing on it) and delivers back to tcp/ip stack or **2)** an app sends data, the module gets the packet (do some processing) and then, delivers the packet to an output NIC.

It is not like a sniffer, in which a copy of the packet is captured while the actual packet flow continues.

I thought on some possibilities to achieve my goal. I thought in registering a **rx_handler** in the kernel to get access to the incoming packets (coming from a NIC), but how to delivers back to the kernel stack? I mean, to allow the packet to follow the path that it should have taken without the module in the middle.

Moreover, let's say an app is sending a packet through TCP protocol. How the module could detour the packet (to literally get the packet)? Is it possible? In order to send it out through the NIC, I think **dev_queue_xmit()** does the job, but I'm not sure.

Does anyone know a possible solution? or any tips?

Basically, I'd like to know if there is a possibility to put a kernel module between the NIC and the MAC layer.. or in the MAC layer to do what I want. In positive case, does anyone has any hint like main kernel functions to use for those purposes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered [libnetfilter_queue](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/index.html) (which works entirely in userspace)? But I am not sure if it supports L2 mangling...Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can hook into kernel networking stack by providing customized callback in place of default *sk_data_ready* function.

```
static void my_sk_data_ready(struct sock *sk, int len) {
        call_customized_logic(sk, len);
        sock_def_readable(sk, len); /* call default callback or not call it */
}
```

Usage:

```
sk->sk_data_ready = my_sk_data_ready;
```